# SUMIFS + INDEX MATCH: how to include duplicate labels across the columns (do not use sumproduct)

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, sumifs

Would someone be able to give me a hand please?

I've an issue whereby I need to include the numbers for duplicated labels across the columns.  I wouldn't want to use the sumproduct option as the file keeps on expanding which means I need to constantly change my range/formula.  The SUMIFS + INDEX MATCH so far has worked very well for all my other files (no matter how many columns/rows are added, I don't need to change the range) - only hit a snag when I have duplicated labels across the columns.

See the example below, I need to pick up all "Team Blue" balances for Jan'20 (which should be $80).  The SUMIFS INDEX MATCH formula only returns the first match for Jan'20 ($10) rather than ($10+$30+$40 =$80). Would you know what changes are required to make the formula work please?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are the teams only ever one row each, or can they appear multiple times in column A?

Answer (score 2):

If a given team is only ever in one row, you can use:

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,I$1,INDEX(B:F,MATCH(H2,A:A,0),0))
```

If not, you want `SUMPRODUCT`.

Answer (score 0):

An array formula would do it

```
=SUM((C2:F2)*($C1:$F1=I1))
```